# How do I save a custom user class attribute in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new at using Django, so pardon if anything in unclear.

Basically, I have created a custom user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('A username is required for you to sign up')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=999)

    points = 0

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'  # Cannot be included in required fields
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    objects = AccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    @staticmethod
    def has_module_perms(app_label):
        return True
```

Under `class Account(AbstractBaseUser)`, I have defined an attribute `points`. I want to make it such that whenever the user redirects, the user gets some points.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def home_page_view(request):
    return render(request, "home_page.html", {})


def free_points(request):
    request.user.points += 10
    request.user.save()
    return render(request, "add_points_test.html", {})
```

To check whether the points has been added, I changed the code under views a little:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def home_page_view(request):
    print(request.user.points)
    return render(request, "home_page.html", {})


def add_points_view(request):
    request.user.points += 10
    request.user.save()
    print(request.user.points)
    return render(request, "add_points_test.html", {})
```

From what I have seen, when the user is redirected to `add_points_view`, the `print` statement under `add_points_view` printed out `10`. However, when the user is redirected back to `home_page_view`, the `print` statement under `home_page_view` printed out `0` instead of `10`. This shows me that `points` hasn't changed at all.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. Sorry if this question is a bad question, I really can't find anything on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is that you didn't define `points` as a persistent field, so even if you call the save method in `add_points_view` the information is gonna be lost.

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/

Comment: So do I change points = 0 to points = models.IntegerField(default=0)?

Comment: @Paul yes, exactly